# Como adicionar várias div's no HTML com javascript sem substituir as já criadas

Tags: javascript, html

// código Js, quando adiciono duas vezes ou mais apenas é criada a última div

```
function Adicionar (nome) {
    
    window.onload = init;
    function init(){

        new CriarElementos();

        function CriarElementos() {
            var NovaDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var NovoH1 = document.createElement('h1');
            var TextoH1 = document.createTextNode(nome);

            NovaDiv.id = 'MeuId';
            NovaDiv.classList.add('margem');

            NovoH1.appendChild(TextoH1);
            document.getElementById('novos').appendChild(NovaDiv);
            document.getElementById('MeuId').appendChild(NovoH1);

        }

    }
}

var objeto =  new Adicionar('Pão');
var objeto2 =  new Adicionar('Leite');
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o problema esta na estrutura do seu codigo, so formos manter ele como estar, basta colocar `window.onload = init()`, executando a funcao `init()` para quando for carregado o `window`.
Agora voce poderia reescrever se codigo para ele ficar mais simples. Primeiro voce tira esse `new` pois nao precisa usar classes, apenas funcoes podem resolver seu problema. Tente fazer algo assim:

```
window.onload = init(); // apos carregar a janela, inicia a funcao init() que tem toda a logia.

    function init() { // Toda sua logica deve ficar aqui dentro.
      function adicionar(nome) {
        function criarElementos() {
          var NovaDiv = document.createElement('div');
          var NovoH1 = document.createElement('h1');
          var TextoH1 = document.createTextNode(nome);

          NovaDiv.id = 'MeuId';
          NovaDiv.classList.add('margem');

          NovoH1.appendChild(TextoH1);
          document.getElementById('novos').appendChild(NovaDiv);
          document.getElementById('MeuId').appendChild(NovoH1);
        }

        criarElementos(); // chame a funcao depois de declara-la.
      }

      adicionar('Pão'); // nao precisa instanciar, apenas execute.
      adicionar('Leite');
      adicionar('Cafe');
      // .....
    }
```

Tente fazer o teste. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Vou testar obrigado